# Splitting a string separated by commas and storing the value into an int array

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, int

I have a string which I want to split by the commas (easy process):

```
String numbers = "1,2,3";
```

But, I then want to convert each element of the split string into an int that can be stored in an int array separated by commas as:

```
int[][] array = new int [0][];
array[0] = new int[] {1,2,3};
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You do not need 2D array. Split the string and parse it to Integer.

Comment: I can parse the string after splitting it into an integer using Integer.parseint() however, I want to know how to create comma separated integers?

Comment: @Yehudah check my answer out. I think it's what you're looking for if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The 2D array is unnecessary. All you need to do is splice the commas out of the string using the `split` method. Then convert each element in the resulting array into an int. Here's what it should look like,

```
String numbers = "1,2,3";
String[] arr = numbers.split(",");
int[] numArr = new int[arr.length];
for(int i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++){
    numArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] strArr = numbers.split(",");
int[][] array = new int[1][];
for(int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    array[0][i] = Integer.parseInt(strArr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need 2D array, you can use simple array. It will be enough to store this data. Just split it by ',' and then iterate through that array,parse everything int and add that parsed values to new array.

```
  String numbers = "1,2,3,4,5";
        String[] splitedArr= numbers.split(",");
        int[] arr = new int[splitedArr.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < splitedArr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitedArr[i]);
        }
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = "1,2,3";

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s,",");
    int[][] array = new int [0][];
    int i = 0;
    while(st.hasMoreElements()) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt((String) st.nextElement());
        array[0][i] = n;
        i++;
    }
```

This is twice as fast as String.split()

Answer (score 0):

```
array[0] = Arrays.stream(numbers.split(","))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .toArray();
```

Comment: this requires jdk 8

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13312634)